# 'TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tuples, typeerror

i am new to python and i'm trying to learn i made this small piece of code

```
weight = input('How much do you weigh in pounds? ')
weight_kg = int(weight)* 0,453592
print (weight_kg + 'is your weight is kilogrammes')
```

but when i run it i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hh/Desktop/PYTHON-LEARNING!/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    print (weight_kg + 'hi')
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Comment: Code and traceback don't match.

Comment: You've created a tuple with that comma on the `weight_kg = ...,...` line. To make a `float` number, use a `.` instead!

Comment: '0,453592', should be '0.453592'

Comment: You'll also have to cast it to a str when trying to concatenate to a string: `str(weight_kg) + '...'`.

Comment: Also once you do the above, you need to either convert the `weight_kg` to a `str` if you want to concat them together `print (str(weight_kg) + ' is your weight is kilogrammes')`, otherwise if you dont want to implicitly convert use a comma instead of a plus `print (weight_kg, 'is your weight is kilogrammes')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here, one is that you multiply by a float with a comma as the decimal separator, and the second is that you can't concatenate a float and a string in a print statement. Below is the fixed code - I use an f-string to print the final output, which requires Python 3.6.

```
weight = input('How much do you weigh in pounds? ')
weight_kg = int(weight)* 0.453592
print (f"{weight_kg} is your weight is kilogrammes")
```